# Migrated Task on Server 2016 Task Scheduler rejected because of missed task start

Tags: windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

this question maybe is connected too ([Windows Server 2016 scheduled task schedule must be in future](https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future?rq=1)) but the issue is still there at our side...

We too migrated from Server 2012 R2 to a new Server 2016 and our Monthly Reboot tasks are not running because of this error.

We have all patches installed as i am aware of and we still face this issue.

The error is

> Task Scheduler did not launch task "\Folder\Reboot_All_Server" as it missed its schedule. Consider using the configuration option to start the task when available, if schedule is missed.

The task category is

> Missed task start rejected

because this task in critical we cannot activate the option **Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed**

Since this worked on Server 2012 this has to work on Server 2016 too...

The Task is configured as

```
Run whether user is logged on or not

Begin the task: On a schedule
Monthly Start 03/03/2019 00:01:00 on First Sunday

Start a program C:\Folder\Reboot_All_Server.cmd

Allow task to be run on demand
Stop the task if it runs longer than: 8 hours
If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop
Do not start a new instance
```

> All other options are not enabled (no tick)

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?
Any known KB Update that has to be installed seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was recognized by microsoft as a bug in the task scheduler code and a hotfix is in work.

Workaround is: Use other start-date that is not in the DST time change range, (or use the checkbox 'synchronize across timezone' to prevent DST time calculations)

Workaround works also if the start-date is in the past.