# Windows Server 2019 scheduled tasks must be in future

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, windows-server-2019

As a follow on to the [Windows Server 016 scheduled task must be in future](https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future), can anyone confirm if the same quirk exists in Windows Server 2019?

When I was tidying up the Task Scheduler Library with some folders to group together tasks, I used the export/import process to copy them from the root folder and into their respective sub-folders. Then I'd run the task manually just to test, and would get an error along the lines of:

```
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Folder\Task Name" task for user "(default user)". 
Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943568.
```

Having never enjoyed much success chasing up error codes, I thought it might have been caused by the export/import process, so I manually created the task again. Start date was today, start time was the time in the morning I wanted the first run to go, which was 7am, and then repeat every hour. I created the task around 11am.

The task saved just fine, however it refused to run manually. The configuration was similar to the screenshot in the previously referenced question.

Some Googling found that question, plus various discussions saying a patch was released in August 2017 for Server 2016, and that now it worked as expected. However I'm finding it isn't, at least for me anyway. If I have to update an existing task, or enter a new one, the start date still needs to be in the future.

Comment: Found this [discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2998579-3d1d-4e74-9eb5-a12ac98d450b/tricky-repeating-scheduled-task-flaw-in-server-2016-apparently-fixed-by-kb4025334?forum=ws2016) about Server 2016, with a link to the KB update.

Comment: The [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025334/windows-10-update-kb4025334) mentions `Addressed issue where a task’s repeat trigger stopped working after reboot.` but apparently that was meant to cover the reboot and the future scheduling problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems your error does not have anything in common with the linked question about task must be in the future.

There is something else wrong with your task or your system.

```
C:\>Err_6.4.5.exe 2147943568
# for decimal -2147023728 / hex 0x80070490
  PEER_E_NOT_FOUND                                               p2p.h
  E_PROP_ID_UNSUPPORTED                                          vfwmsgs.h
# The specified property ID is not supported for the
# specified property set.%0
  WER_E_NOT_FOUND                                                werapi.h
  DRM_E_NOT_FOUND                                                windowsplayready.h
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x490
# for decimal 1168 / hex 0x490
  ERROR_NOT_FOUND                                                winerror.h
# Element not found.
# 5 matches found for "2147943568"
```

So the result seems to be **0x80070490** which translates to "Element not found" errors.

You have to check every step of your task like what actions are performed with what parameters and so on. Also try to start the desired action/command yourself in a cmd box started with the credentials the task is using. PSExec can also help to test the launch of commands as a system user.